# Integer to String conversion methods

Tags: java

What are the alternative methods for converting and integer to a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert from int to String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Integer.toString(your_int_value);
```

or

```
your_int_value+"";
```

and, of course, Java Docs should be best friend in this case.

Comment: `your_edit_value + "";` causes the allocation of an extra empty string object, call `Integer.toString(your_int_value)` and concatenates both of them. 3 strings allocations where the first statement requires only one. The first one is faster.

Comment: the seoncd version is awful. Java is not PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: Implicit conversion to `String` has a big downside. `val1 + val2 + ""` is **very** different from `"" + val1 + val2`

Comment: yes, totally agree value+""; is not a good approach. i was just trying to mention different ways of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

```
String one = Integer.toString(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String myString = Integer.toString(myInt);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are all the different versions:

a) Convert an Integer to a String

```
Integer one = Integer.valueOf(1);
String oneAsString = one.toString();
```

b) Convert an int to a String

```
int one = 1;
String oneAsString = String.valueOf(one);
```

c) Convert a String to an Integer

```
String oneAsString = "1";
Integer one = Integer.valueOf(oneAsString);
```

d) Convert a String to an int

```
String oneAsString = "1";
int one = Integer.parseInt(oneAsString);
```

There is also a page in the Sun Java tutorial called [Converting between Numbers and Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
String.valueOf(anyInt);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `Integer.toString()` or you can use string concatenation where 1st operand is string (even empty): `String snr = "" + nr;`. This can be useful if you want to add more items to String variable.

Comment: I think both are useful. Example: if you want to convert some number to string in loop then you can use `new_name = old_name + i + ".txt"` or `new_name = old_name + Integer.toString(i) + ".txt"`. In this case I prefer shorter method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.valueOf(thenumber)` for conversion. But if you plan to add another word converting is not nessesary. You can have something like this:
`String string = "Number: " + 1`
This will make the string equal Number: 1.