# Problems converting Integer to String

Tags: java, android, string, integer

I am trying to add two numbers together from EditText fields. So far I have the code below that I believe converts the EditText field 'pos1_deg' & 'pos2_deg' into integers deg1 & deg2.

```
deg1 = Integer.parseInt(pos1_deg.getText().toString());
deg2 = Integer.parseInt(pos2_deg.getText().toString());
```

I could then do the following to add them together

```
degSum = deg1 + deg2
```

And then the degSum register holds the sum of deg1 & 2. Is this correct so far?

Then to output back to the 'result' EditText I need to change the integer degSum into a string. I thought the correct way was to use the code below:

```
result.setText(degSum.toString());
```

However I get an 'Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int' error. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: There was another question one hour ago that gives an answer: [How to convert from integer to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string)

Comment: Just to clear something up 'degSum' is not a register, it is a variable. In this context, the term 'register' would mean a specific feature as implemented by the CPU which provides a location which is capable of having operations performed upon it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Assuming this is Java...)

The message is correct.  Primitive values (such as `int`) cannot have methods invoked on them as they are not objects.  The associated methods are instead registered on the `Integer` class statically, so instead you should use:

```
result.setText(Integer.toString(degSum));
```

(This method also takes an optional second argument that lets you specify the base that you want the number output in, so you can get the hexadecimal representation by calling `Integer.toString(degSum, 16)` for example.  Probably not what you need *right* now but worth bearing in mind.)

Answer (score 1):

When you concatanate a String to a non-String the result is a String.

e.g.

```
int deg1 = 5;
int deg2 = 4;
result.setText("" + deg1 + deg2): // passes in "45" (a String)
result.setText("" + (deg1 + deg2)): // passes in "9" (a String)
result.setText(deg1 + deg2); // passes in 9 (an int), compile error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(deg_sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to do String.valueOf(deg_sum)
2. You can make your degSum not int, but Integer, so the toString method will be available.