# Why cannot cast Integer to String in java?

Tags: java, string, casting, integer

I found some strange exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer 
 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How it can be possible? Each object can be casted to String, doesn't it?

The code is:

```
String myString = (String) myIntegerObject;
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"Each object can be casted to String"_ -- This is wrong. Rather, every object has a `toString()` method that will convert it to a String. As several answers point out, that is what you should use. (For some objects, `toString()` doesn't return a very _useful_ string, but for `Integer`, it probably does exactly what you want.)

Comment: `""+myIntegerObject` also works :)

Comment: In my case, this error was reported in fault... I was using `Integer.toString(IntegerObject)` and it gave me this error, but it's happy with `IntegerObject.toString()`... And yes, that really is an Integer, and I really did get this error...

Comment: Scratch that, only `String.valueOf()` actually works...

Answer (score 176, accepted):

**Why this is not possible:**

Because String and Integer are not in the same Object hierarchy.

```
      Object
     /      \
    /        \
String     Integer
```

The casting which you are trying, works only if they are in the same hierarchy, e.g.

```
      Object
     /
    /
   A
  /
 /
B
```

In this case, `(A) objB` or `(Object) objB` or `(Object) objA` will work.

Hence as others have mentioned already, to convert an integer to string use:

`String.valueOf(integer)`, or `Integer.toString(integer)` for primitive,

**or**

`Integer.toString()` for the object.

Comment: What about (A) objA, (B) objB and (B) objA?

Comment: @su-ex  `(B) objA` won't work. `(A) objA` and `(B) objB` will work.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, this gives a ClassCastException. The other two are quite useless but will work of course.

Answer (score 51):

No, `Integer` and `String` are different types. To convert an integer to string use: `String.valueOf(integer)`, or `Integer.toString(integer)` for primitive, or `Integer.toString()` for the object.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - which one? If it is a primitive use the first two, if it is the Integer object use the third one.

Comment: Oops. I didn't see that last phrase of your answer. I'm deleting my comment and upvoting this answer.

Comment: Similar (but not duplicate) issue: an ['int' cannot be cast to a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105655/problems-converting-integer-to-string) because an 'int' is not an object, much less in the String hierarchy.

Comment: All answers acceptable (Petar knows his stuff) and while the primitives versus object options in Java static utilities can be exasperating... the general rationale to the OP's question is effectively "any integer can be a String but not every string can be an integer". Also take care with sorting. A list of bonafide integers as String types does not have the same natural order sorting as a list of actual integer types.

Answer (score 22):

For `int` types use:

```
int myInteger = 1;
String myString = Integer.toString(myInteger);
```

For `Integer` types use:

```
Integer myIntegerObject = new Integer(1);
String myString = myIntegerObject.toString();
```

Comment: This forces an unnecessary unboxing operation.

Comment: @Ted Hopp see my edits to clarify when to use each type of `toString()` method

Comment: I think that last line should be `String myString = myIntegerObject.toString();`

Answer (score 6):

No. Every object can be casted to an `java.lang.Object`, not a `String`. If you want a string representation of whatever object, you have to invoke the `toString()` method; this is *not* the same as casting the object to a String.

Answer (score 6):

You can't cast explicitly anything to a `String` that isn't a `String`. You should use either:

```
"" + myInt;
```

or:

```
Integer.toString(myInt);
```

or:

```
String.valueOf(myInt);
```

I prefer the second form, but I think it's personal choice.

**Edit** OK, here's why I prefer the second form. The first form, when compiled, could instantiate a `StringBuffer` (in Java 1.4) or a `StringBuilder` in 1.5; one more thing to be garbage collected. The compiler doesn't optimise this as far as I could tell. The second form also has an analogue, `Integer.toString(myInt, radix)` that lets you specify whether you want hex, octal, etc. If you want to be consistent in your code (purely aesthetically, I guess) the second form can be used in more places.

**Edit 2** I assumed you meant that your integer was an `int` and not an `Integer`. If it's already an `Integer`, just use `toString()` on it and be done.

Comment: OP is starting with an Integer object. It's much more efficient to just do `myIntegerObject.toString()`.

Answer (score 5):

Objects can be *converted* to a string using the `toString()` method:

```
String myString = myIntegerObject.toString();
```

There is no such rule about *casting*. For casting to work, the object must actually be of the type you're casting to.

Answer (score 4):

You should call myIntegerObject.toString() if you want the string representation.

Answer (score 3):

Casting is different than converting in Java, to use informal terminology.

Casting an object means that object already is what you're casting it to, and you're just telling the compiler about it. For instance, if I have a `Foo` reference that I know is a `FooSubclass` instance, then `(FooSubclass)Foo` tells the compiler, "don't change the instance, just know that it's actually a `FooSubclass`.

On the other hand, an `Integer` is *not* a `String`, although (as you point out) there are methods for getting a `String` that represents an `Integer`. Since no no instance of `Integer` can ever be a `String`, you can't cast `Integer` to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case don't need casting, you need call toString().

```
Integer i = 33;
String s = i.toString();
//or
s = String.valueOf(i);
//or
s = "" + i;
```

Casting. How does it work?

Given:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

> (A) 
>   
>   |
> (B)

```
B b = new B(); //no cast
A a = b;  //upcast with no explicit cast
a = (A)b; //upcast with an explicit cast
b = (B)a; //downcast
```

A and B in the same inheritance tree and we can this:

```
a = new A();
b = (B)a;  // again downcast. Compiles but fails later, at runtime: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

The compiler must allow things that might possibly work at runtime. However, if the compiler knows with 100% that the cast couldn't possibly work, compilation will fail.

Given:

```
class A {}
class B1 extends A {}
class B2 extends A {}
```

> (A) 
>   
>       /       \
> (B1)       (B2)

```
B1 b1 = new B1();
B2 b2 = (B2)b1; // B1 can't ever be a B2
```

Error: Inconvertible types B1 and B2.
The compiler knows with 100% that the cast couldn't possibly work. But you can cheat the compiler:

```
B2 b2 = (B2)(A)b1;
```

but anyway at runtime:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: B1 cannot be cast to B2

**in your case:**

> (Object)
>             /       \
> (Integer)       (String)

```
Integer i = 33;
//String s = (String)i; - compiler error
String s = (String)(Object)i;
```

at runtime: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.valueOf(integer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29).

It returns a string representation of integer.

Comment: As Petar says above, that should be ``String.valueOf(integer)``

Comment: @UrsReupke: thanks, actually when i was trying to add the link i re-wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use .toString instead like below:

```
String myString = myIntegerObject.toString();
```