# This method of type casting is not working

Tags: java, casting

```
package coding;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class casting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new  Scanner(System.in);
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        int b=(int)a;
        System.out.println(b);



    }

}
```

In above code it is giving error casting from string to int is not possible
if i replace `int b=(int)a; to int b=Integer.parseInt(a);` then it's working fine
pls tell me why `int b=(int)a;` is not working.

Comment: You can't cast a string to an int.

Comment: Read the documentation for the method Integer.parseInt().

Comment: The answer for you is in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973381/why-cannot-cast-integer-to-string-in-java

Comment: Are you python or php programmer? where was is it possible? to ask this is not happening in Java?