# read() method of BufferedReader and InputStreamReader

Tags: java

Why do I get an exception when parsing the characters to integer using the `read()` method instead of `readLine()` of `BufferedReader`. I tried using this code below:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int a= Integer.parseInt(br.read());
```

> error was : cannot convert int to string.. very strange error

Comment: try with this  `Integer.toString(integer)` FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973381/why-cannot-cast-integer-to-string-in-java

Comment: No i do not want to convert integer to string. that is why i wrote strange errror.. as i want to convert character into integer using read method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reader.read()` just returns a single character - but as an `int`, so you can tell if you've reached the end of the data.

Now there isn't any `Integer.parseInt(int)` method, which is why the calling is failing - there isn't even `Integer.parseInt(char)`. You could convert to `char` and then call `Character.getNumericValue(char)`... or you could just use:

```
int digit = br.read() - '0';
```

... and then check that `digit` is in the range 0-9.

Alternatively you *could* create a string from the single character you've read and call `Integer.parseInt`, but that seems like overkill...

Comment: can u please tell what basically this '0' is doing in your code : (((int digit = br.read() - '0';))))

Comment: @Isha: That's subtracting the UTF-16 code unit for the digit 0... basically the integer you get is the UTF-16 code unit for the character in the input, and you want to convert '0' to an integer 0, '1' to an integer 1 etc... as the code units for '0' to '9' are contiguous, you can just subtract '0'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse `String` in `Integer.parseInt("need a String")`.

But here you are providing `int`. `br.read()` return an `int`

You can use

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int a= br.read();
```

Edit:

Yes, when you enter `5`, `br.read()` read is as `53`, since unicode value of   '5'  is 53.

So you want to deal with `int`. you can try `int a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());`

Comment: I want to parse the number like 4 or 5 or any integer value which is is read as character through read() method

Comment: @Isha yes. You can try this way.

Comment: When you say "or any integer value" you mean "any single digit" right? Because `read()` only reads a single character... how would you expect to read the number 1234 that way?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes here m talking about single digit number only. N i had already tried the way you had told me, but in output some other no. is coming ( i guess its the ASCII value). For. eg. if i input 5 , then when i am printing that number, some other number is coming.

Comment: @Isha: Then you're not doing what's in my answer (not this one), as what's in my answer works. But we can't see what you're doing, because you haven't provided the code you've tried, which makes it really hard to help you...

Comment: @Isha yes.. That is also known.... you should aware that... see my edit...
when you enter 5, br.read() read is as 53, since unicode value of '5' is 53

Comment: @JonSkeet i have provided the lines of code where the problem was coming. Again have a look. And yes i have not tried your way completely but somewhat similar to it was done by me

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera sir i am aware that i can do this with readLine(). Question was about read(). :)

Comment: @Isha Yes.. as I explain here you will not able to do what you trying with read(). you need to read Java doc as well. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()

Answer (score 0):

Use `readLine()` function. In this case value is read as a string.

```
 int a= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

The `read()` method returns a character as an integer.`parseInt()` expects a string but you are giving an integer. So here the code `int a= Integer.parseInt(br.read())` tries to convert int to int. Hence the error.

Comment: Yes m aware that i can do this using readLine(). But the question why we can't do it with read()

Answer (score 0):

`Reader` and its subclasses contains the `int read()` method, which reads a single character as an `int`.

The reason it returns an `int` instead of `char` is because it must be able to return -1 when end of stream has been reached (as well as the 65536 characters that `char` provides).

If you want to read a single character, you can just check that the value wasn't -1 and then cast it to char. If you want to treat the character as an int value, you don't need to do anything.