# What is the value type of the Map?

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
  private def buildProps(host: => String)(config: => List[KafkaConfig]) =
    (config.map {
      case ClientId(value: String) =>
        (ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, value)
      case Acks(value: String) =>
        (ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, value)
      case Retries(value) =>
        (ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, value)
      case BatchSize(value) =>
        (ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, value)
      case LingerMs(value) =>
        (ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, value)
      case BufferMemory(value) =>
        (ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, value)
    } ++ List(
      (ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, host),
      (ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"),
      (ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"))
      ).toMap
```

What is the type of the value from `Map(String, ????)`? 
The type `value` of the case is very mixed:

```
final case class ClientId(value: String) extends KafkaConfig

final case class Acks(value: String) extends KafkaConfig

final case class Retries(value: java.lang.Integer) extends KafkaConfig

final case class BatchSize(value: java.lang.Integer) extends KafkaConfig

final case class LingerMs(value: java.lang.Integer) extends KafkaConfig

final case class BufferMemory(value: java.lang.Integer) extends KafkaConfig
```

Some are `Strings` and another are `Integers`.

Comment: Looks like `AnyRef`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is AnyRef because that's what java class types usually roll up to. 
Also, in java they meet at the object level.

https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/71%3Fsize=_original.html#

[Why cannot cast Integer to String in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973381/why-cannot-cast-integer-to-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to check for yourself is to give a clearly incorrect type:

```
private def buildProps(host: => String)(config: => List[KafkaConfig]): Int = ...
```

You'll see an error like the following:

```
Error:(*line*, *column*) type mismatch;
 found   : *the type you are interested in*
 required: Int
```