# How to solve the following error in android parsing value

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

I'm new in Android and I want to get an integer value to String variable to set that value to TextView

Comment: DuplicateSee post : Problems converting Integer to String for your answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/4105655/594773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 12;
String str = String.valueOf(i); // one option
str = "" + i; // two options
Integer num = i;
str = num.toString();
```

You should always try to find the answer yourself before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:-

```
(integerValue).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this.

```
String str = Integer.toString(integer_variable);
```