# android - how to convert int to string and place it in a EditText?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, integer, type-conversion

I have this piece of code:

```
ed = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.box); 
int x = 10; 
ed.setText (x);
```

It turns out to be an error. I know I have to change it to string, but how do I do this?

I've tried `x.toString()`, but it can't be compiled.

Comment: In this case, ask a new question re: `char`. (Hint: the answer is to turn the `char` into a `String`, and `Integer.parseInt()` the string.)

Comment: why you not try it from google it s so easy to get this answer?

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question at a time in a post. I have edited out your second question, ask this as a new question instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert from int to String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `+`, the [string concatenation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) operator:

```
ed = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.box);
int x = 10;
ed.setText(""+x);
```

or use [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29):

```
ed.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```

or use [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29):

```
ed.setText(Integer.toString(x));
```

Answer (score 9):

try `Integer.toString(integer value);` method as

```
ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box);
int x = 10;
ed.setText(Integer.toString(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String.format()` :

```
ed = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.box); 
int x = 10; 
ed.setText(String.format("%s",x));
```

Answer (score 1):

`ed.setText (String.ValueOf(x));`

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code:

```
String.valueOf(x);
```