# Why is my button crashing my app?

Tags: android, string, button, android-edittext, oncreate

I am having a problem when I press my button to store my EditText info to a string the app crashes and I can't find any problem's, am I setting something up wrong and I just don't see it?

```
public class Tab5 extends Activity {

Button btnGo ;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab5);

    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText userid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            userid.setText(2);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Tab5.this, Tab1.class);
            userid.getText().toString();
            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

}
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: EditText are meant to get input from the user. So thers no point setting a value to it. First please instantiate it outside your onClick() then on the button click get the text entered by userid.getText().toString(); which you can use later. It isnt being used at the moment.

Comment: @AtulOHolic what am i doing wrong that isn't getting the text when the button is clicked

Comment: setText() will take String, however 2 is an int so you will either have to do String.valueOf(2) or "2". But I m curious to know why you wanna do that if you yourself want to setText then you directly do it, why using an EditText?

Comment: @AtulOHolic i am running a tabhosted webview app with a different webview in every tab, however all of the webview url's end with ?id=* and i want what ever they type in to be the value of "*" and have 2 as the default load, what would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have ?id= assigned to a variable as

```
public final static String URL = "outputapps.com/build/infoview.php?id=";
```

and then can concatenate the EditText value but as you said you need 2 to be the default we will have to check EditText first if it contains any text or not. DO this is Tab5

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Tab5.this, Tab1.class);
String edit = userid.getText().toString();
String myURL = null;
if(edit != null && edit.length > 0){
    myURL = edit;
}else{
    myURL = "2";
}
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_URL", myURL);
startActivity(intent);
```

then for loading the URL do this in your Tab1,

```
String myURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_URL");
webView.loadUrl(YourActivity.URL + myURL);
```

I know the above can be written in fewer lines but I hope this is clear. Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: the url is in another activity how would i use that in this setting

       
 private WebView webView;
  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
  
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  webView.loadUrl("http://outputapps.com/build/infoview.php?id=");
  webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
  
 }
}'

Comment: you can pass the url as an Intent extra and incase it is fixed i.e. always going to be same then you can create it as a static String and access directly as Classname.url wherever you want. Keep public access in this case. See I have edited the URL above is in the Activty you want.

Comment: i keep messing up or something, thank you so much for all this help, i have no idea why this isnt working here are some screen shots of the code http://gyazo.com/dcf4e7296500a101f787c31306799019 that is where the webview is that needs to pull the variable and this is where the edittext is http://gyazo.com/710aefbd3d6948bdc8392bc777cde55a

Comment: Please don't kill me for choosing wrong variable name. final is a keyword  and hence the issue, change it to something else like final_URL or something. :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to further explain how we can pass your String from Tab5 to Tab1 via an intent.

Comment: if you could please further help me i ran into another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638780/error-reloading-webviews-in-a-tabhost-with-a-button

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
userid.setText(2);
```

Android will think of that int ad a resourceId, and will not find it in the R.java.

So just remember to pass always String to the setText method

```
userid.setText(String.valueOf(2));
```

or

```
userid.setText(""+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 userid.setText("2");
```

instead of

```
 userid.setText(2);
```

Comment: ok so in my app i have 5 different webviews in different tab's all of the url's end with ?id= and i want the id to equal what i type in, on click of the button i want it to refresh all of the webviews but now when i click the button (that fixed it by the way thanks) it just opens a new webview and gets rid of my tabhost?

Comment: Please see this for reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542982/android-webview-stay-in-app

Comment: If the answer help you vote for them it might help other too and anyway I am not getting what exactly you want...kindly put some code

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a int to an EditText. Convert the int to String. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659230/android-how-to-convert-int-to-string-and-place-it-in-edittext):

> Use +, the string concatenation operator:
>
> ```
> ed = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.box);
> int x = 10;
> ed.setText(""+x);
> ```
>
> or use `String.valueOf(int)`:
>
> ```
> ed.setText(String.valueOf(x));
> ```
>
> or use `Integer.toString(int)`:
>
> ```
> ed.setText(Integer.toString(x))
> ```