# Assigning file filled with number values to a 2D array of JLabels

Tags: java, jlabel

```
107054600
003008529
000000070
004905100
800700900
012003000
700000006
200609004
036010000
```

The files store a Sudoku puzzle in this way.

I have to be able to read these puzzles into both a 2d int array and a 2d Jlabel array.

It works when reading into the Int array alone. However, when I try assign the icon value of the j Label with the current number being processed by the for loop I get this compiler error:

> The constructor javax.swing.JLabel(int) is undefined

Why is this?

The relevant code is below:

```
JLabel[][] gridLabels = new JLabel[9][9];
int [][] grid = new int [9][9];  // Game Array

try {
 String fileName1 = new Scanner(new File("./temp.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
 Scanner fin;
 fin = new Scanner( new File(fileName1));
 //Reads in the puzzle from a temporary text file

 for(int row=0; row<9; row++)
{
 String line = fin.next();
 for(int col=0; col<9; col++)
  { grid[row][col] = line.charAt(col)-'0'; 
   gridLabels[row][col] = new JLabel(line.charAt(col)-'0');    //PROBLEM HERE//
  }
 }
  } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
  {System.out.println("Incorrect Selection"); // Catches incorrect selection
  }
  catch (NoSuchElementException exception)
  {System.out.println("No Such Element");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result of `line.charAt(col)-'0'` is an `int` and the error says that `JLabel` does not have any constructor that takes an `int` argument.

Try `new JLabel(String.valueOf(line.charAt(col)-'0'))`.

Answer (score 1):

In constructor for `javax.swing.JLabel` you can pass a `String` but not an `int`.
You should convert your `int` to `String` before passing it to `Label` constructor.
You can do conversion from `int` to `String` as `String.valueOf(i)`.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string) for conversion