# cannot convert an Int to String

Tags: java

I want to convert a int to String in java but I can't :

this is the code I used :

```
 jTextField1.setText((String)l.getCode());
```

and this is the error I got :

```
Inconvertible types
required:java.lang.String
found:   int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways you convert an integer to string firstly using the built-in converter,

```
jTextField1.setText("" + l.getCode())
```

Secondly you could use the static method toString(int) of the Integer class,

```
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(l.getCode()))
```

You could also use a formatter but this in not recommended as it just makes the code cumbersome and difficult to understand.

```
jTextField1.setText(String.format("%d", l.getCode()))
```

Comment: RE "" + int: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string

Answer (score 9):

You can not typecast `int` to `string` try below code.

```
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(l.getCode()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
   Integer.toString(l.getCode);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

`Integer.valueOf(l.getCode()).toString()`

You cannot convert `int` simple type to `String` object.

Comment: [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) or [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could try:

```
String.valueOf(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(l.getCode()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(l.getCode()));
```

Comment: You should innest properly the brackets... as it is now it will not compile

Comment: @araknoid yes it will. The only difference between this answer and yours is this one has a line terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(l.getCode()));
```