# Java: Returning a String of a primitive type

Tags: java, primitive

I have a variable of type "long"

```
 long time = System.currntTimeMillis();
```

I would like to pass it to a method that requires a string. If this wasn't a primative type I would call time.toString(): but that is not a valid method.

What I am doing is

```
 method("" + time);
```

And this creates a string, but is there a better way or more optimal way to do this?

Comment: Your approach is fine.

Comment: it works but I don't like it personally. Suppose you have a `Long` instead of `long` and suppose you forget to initialize it. You will call `method("null");` and have some parsing issues instead of NPE or even worse : never raise any error. Long.toString(long) will throw a NPE which is far more easier to investigate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

`Long.toString(time)` or `String.valueOf(time)`.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105406/1651233)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
method(Long.toString(time));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 method("" + time);
```

is inefficient. String API exposes lots of static [utility overloaded methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for different types:

```
String.valueOf(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
method(String.valueof(time));
```