# Convert loop index to string

Tags: java, type-mismatch

Okay so I want to create a for loop that assigns variables with each increment of `i`. This is what I have, but it doesn't work due to a type mismatch:

```
int i;
String d;
for(i = 5; i > 0; i--){
String.valueOf(i);
d = i;
d = reader.readLine();
System.out.println(d);
}
```

So the error that I get right now is "type mismatch" when setting `d = i`. Obviously I get the error due to `d` not being an int but a String, but I thought `String.valueOf(i)` was supposed to convert `i` to a String? I must have misunderstood this. What am I doing wrong in this or what is another way to do this?

Comment: `d = Integer.toString(i);`

Comment: or d=String.valueOf(i);

Comment: Or `Integer.parseInt(d);` Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string

Answer (score 2):

`String.valueOf(i)` *returns* a string representation of `i`. You're throwing that away, by executing this as a statement.

Did you intend `d = String.valueOf(i);`, perhaps?

(Just a guess. Since you promptly overwrite d in the following line, I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish.)

Comment: This actually explains the mistake in contrast with the other answers that just provide an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can implicitly convert `i` to a `String` by doing `"" + i`

```
int i;
String d;
for(i = 5; i > 0; i--){
   d = "" + i;
   System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  If you want to just output

5 4 3 2 1

then try:

```
int i;
String d;
for(i = 5; i > 0; i--){
d = String.valueOf(i);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println( " " );
}
```