# Java: is there a better way to change in to string than this?

Tags: java, tostring

Is there a shorter hand way (more space savy) way to compact a `toString` than this?

```
int number = 20;
String numberChange = Integer.toString(number);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string

Comment: What do you mean by "space savy [sic]"?  If you would like your source file to use 13 fewer bytes on your 750GB hard drive, then the answers will help you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java will convert things to string when adding something to a string.

```
String numberChange = ""+number;
```