# What's this Java idiom? String constructor with concatenation

Tags: java, idioms

In a code base I'm working with I'm seeing this idiom being used.Can someone explain it for me?

```
new String("" + number) // `i` is an instance of Integer
```

For some context, this is approximately what the method looks like:

```
public String someMethod(String numberString) {
    Integer number = new Integer(numberString);
    // other stuff happens...
    return new String("" + number);
}
```

Comment: I'd say the author was inexperienced with Java.  Don't know any reason you'd do that.

Comment: and also there is Integer.toString() :-)

Comment: Aside from chopping ridiculously long digits into `Integer`s, I can't think of any real use for this. And then why translate it back to a string?

Comment: This is just crap. Once the number has been concatenated with a string it does not need to be handed to the constructor of another string. It's very poor programming and you should delete it.

Comment: Actually, I'm commenting on the method you posted. The `"" + number`, which is equivalent to `new String("" + number)`, is indeed a shortcut to translating an int to a string. Should really be `(new Integer(number)).toString()` or `String.valueOf(number)`

Comment: Using `new String(...)` may even avoid the intern pool, and so is less efficient in terms of memory than `"" + number`. Someone please correct me if I'm mistaken here.

Comment: Writer didn't know `String.valueOf(...)`, or it was too much typing for him/her

Comment: @WilliamMorrison No magic intern() happen here. It just more verbose as well as slower.  Code which doesn't do anything is the hardest to reason about because it doesn't have a reason to be there.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `""+someNumber` doesn't use the intern pool behind the scenes then?

Comment: @WilliamMorrison only String literals do, unless you changed the code yourself ;)

Comment: Kind of silly to use `new String(someString)` in about 95% of the cases where you see it.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison - I don't think the compiler would cast `""+someNumber` into a String literal, but it's pretty silly to turn around and use that value for the argument to a String constructor regardless.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks, peter corrected me already. I don't know why I ever thought this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely nothing but an inexperienced Java programmers attempt at converting a number to a String.

Whether converting numbers to Strings using `"" + number` is good practice [is debateable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string). I for one find `String.valueOf(number)` to be more clear (although it's semantically equivalent).

It's completely unnecessary to wrap the result in `new String(...)` unless you (for some unimaginable reason) really need a *new string*, i.e. one that's referentially distinct from other strings.

Comment: `String.valueOf(number)` will just call `number.toString()` in this case.

Comment: Right. As long as `number` is non-null.

Comment: As long as `number` is not changed, `new Integer(s)` should never be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

This ideom is the easiest way of converting any primitive or Object type to a string.

It is quite easy: Typing `"" + number` is less work than typing `String.valueOf(number)` (or `Integer.toString(number)`. The latter is the usual way of transforming an `int` into a `String`. Which one is clearer and to be preferred is a matter of taste. You will find advocates for both versions.

*But note three things:*

1. Calling `String.valueOf(number)` is faster, because `"" + number` will become a string concatenation, it will be compiled to

   ```
   new StringBuilder().append("").append(number).toString()
   ```

   *However, unless this statement is in a hot place in your code, the difference will not matter at all. Even in a hot place, the difference might still be negligible*
2. Simply calling `number.toString()` is also an option since `number` is a boxed integer. However, if `number` is null, this will trigger a null pointer exception so be careful!
3. The last line of your example, i.e., `new String("" + number);` is simply crap! It wraps the result into a newly built string. This creates an unnecessary copy and costs precious extra keystrokes. It also generates unnecessary boilerplate noise in your code. This last line compiles to:

   ```
   new String(new StringBuilder().append("").append(number).toString())
   ```

   That is quite some work for transforming `int` to String. You first create a StringBuilder, then a built String and then a copy of this built String. This creates three objects instead of one.

Comment: But why `new String(...)` instead of just `"" + number`?

Comment: And `"" + number` doesn't express what you're trying to do nearly as clearly as `number.toString()` or `String.valueOf(number)`, IMO.

Comment: I think `""+number` is still clearer than `((Integer)number).toString();`. Anyways, it's basically `number to String conversion`. As for why they used the explicit constructor for the creation of the String rather than the result of the concatenation, I'm not sure myself. I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: +1 While `"" + i` is slower for the computer it is faster for the developer which is often worth much more, still clarity is the most important thing and which one you prefer is a matter of taste.

Comment: @aioobe: Edited my answer. The `new String(...)` is crap.

Comment: You forgot that the StringBuilder has a `char[]` and this has to be copied to another `char[]` for the String and possibly copied again, though most likely not.

Comment: @Zhuinden `String.valueOf(number)` is more clear than `"" + number`

Comment: @Zhuinden: Why would you cast it to `Integer` first? No-one has suggested that.

Comment: Technically they didn't because the example above already created an Integer object so the casting was not necessary. But if you have a vanilla (primitive) `int` then you have to go all the way with the effort.

Comment: @aioobe - You are correct in observing that the `new String()` op is totally wasted motion.

Answer (score 0):

This idiom is used to automatically convert the integer `number` to a string.

The `String` constructor expects an argument of type `String`. The expression `new String(number)` would not compile. Concatenting an empty string is a little trick to turn the Integer into a String.

You could of course use `new String(number.toString())` or `String.valueOf(number)` instead.

*Note:* As Jon Skeet mentions in the comments there is no need to use `new Sring()` at all. You could just `return number.toString();` or `return String.valueOf(number)`