# Compilation error - incompatible types

Tags: java

I am working on a program and I've got the massage:

error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String if(Double.parseDouble(obtenerMedallasEqu(nombre)) > promedio())

when I tried to compilate it. To be honest, I've no idea of how to correct this error.

The methods, that are relevant for this part of the code

```
public int obtenerMedallasEqu(String nombre){
    int i = 0;
    int medallas = 0;
    while (i<cantEquipos){
        if(equipos[i].getNombre().equals(nombre))
            medallas = medallas + equipos[i].getOro() + equipos[i].getPlata() + equipos[i].getBronce();
    i++;
    }
    return medallas;
}
public double promedio(){
    return (olimpiadasant[0] + olimpiadasant[1] + olimpiadasant[2] + olimpiadasant[3] + olimpiadasant[4])/5;
}

public String medallasOlimp(){
    int i = 0;
    String resultado = "";
    String nombre = "";
    while(i < cantEquipos){
        if(Double.parseDouble(obtenerMedallasEqu(nombre)) > promedio())
            resultado = "La cantidad de medallas obtenidas en Londres del " + i + " equipo es \n mayor que el promedio de medallas obtenidas en las \n 5 olimpiadas precedentes.";
        i++;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Maybe you guys can help me, or at least give me a tip of how to resolve it.
Already thank you.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: parseDouble requires String not int. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at `Double.parseDouble(obtenerMedallasEqu(nombre))`. `obtenerMedallasEqu(nombre)` has a return type of `int`. However, `Double.parseDouble(String s)` is expecting a string, not an int. Hence your error. It seems the `Double.parseDouble(..)` call is unnecessary - it's already an int, you don't need to *parse* anything to a double. Try changing the line to:

```
if( ((double) obtenerMedallasEqu(nombre)) > promedio())
```