# How do i rename a integer to a string

Tags: java

How do I replace the number that the user inputs as their choice with the actual corresponding string that their choice means in the print line.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class MagicGame
{
  public static void main(String [] args)

  {

    String name;
    int userCharacter;
    int armorChoice;
    int weaponChoice;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Please enter your name");
    name = input.nextLine();
    { 
    System.out.println("Please select the character you would like to play:" + '\n' + "1 for Magic User" + '\n' + "2 for Fighter" + '\n' + "3 for Thief" + '\n' + "4 for Druid" );
    userCharacter = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please select your Armor Type:" + '\n' + "1 for Steel plate – Armor Class 10" + '\n' + "2 for Chain mail – Armor Class 5" + '\n' + "3 for Leather armor – Armor Class 3" + '\n' + "4 for A robe – Armor Class 1");
    armorChoice = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please choose a Weapon:" + '\n' + "1 for Sword" + '\n' + "2 for Short Sword" + '\n' + "3 for Scimitar" + '\n' + "4 for Dagger");
    weaponChoice = input.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Hello " + name + "! You chose to play a " + userCharacter + "." + '\n' + "Your armor is" + armorChoice + "." + '\n' + "You will be fighting with a " + weaponChoice + ".");
  }
}
```

It is longer but I had to trim it down.

Comment: to parse an int to a String: `String.parseInt(myInt)`. Or to simply print an int, `System.out.println("" + myInt);`

Comment: ... or `String foo = String.valueOf(1);` please search first - see for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string

Comment: What are you asking? `String.valueOf(int)`, `Integer.parseInt(String)` or something else?

Comment: ok, here is my code gist.github.com/anonymous/a896b9f3ea0ba7449b25 i need to replace the number with the corresponding string in the print line

Comment: @John you can edit the question and paste code here

Comment: Please post all code here, not in a link.

Comment: it says my code it too long to post here

Answer (score 0):

Which programming language?

**Java:**

```
String s = String.valueOf(123);
String s = 123 + "";
```

**C++**

```
int a = 10;
stringstream ss;
ss << a;
string str = ss.str();
```

**C++0x**

```
std::string s = std::to_string(42);
```

**C#**

```
string s = myInt.ToString();
```

Comment: ok, here is my code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a896b9f3ea0ba7449b25 i need to replace the number with the corresponding string in the print line

Comment: use that as a question.  Your original question is awful.