# Log is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have very strange problem in eclipse for java (android programming)

This is ALL of my code : 
(an array and site of that array into int value)

```
    int[] Values = new int[]{ 5, 12, 4, 2, 4 };
    int Size = Values.length;
    Log.i(Size);
error --^
```

eclipse gives this error :

**The method i(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (int)**

What is the problem ?

**How to solve it?**

Comment: Problem is well explained in the message you posted.

Comment: @Nambari i am learning from a video, that videos is ok with that code, but i have problem with it. Just i see error and no error is in videos.

Comment: Does the video use capital letters for the variable names as in your code? If so, I would probably try to grab a different video... it's teaching you bad habits.

Comment: Nothing wrong in learning from video, just spend few minutes to understand what the message saying instead of simply posting to some forum. That helps you in accelerating your learning.

Comment: The `Log.i()` method takes two strings as arguments and you are giving it one integer. What do you think you have to change in order to fix your problem? Give it two strings, as intended...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message pretty much tells you what is wrong: You can't pass a single `int` to the method `i()` because it has two `String` as parameter.

See also the [documentation for the `Log` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) in the Android API.

You have to pass two strings as described in the linked documentation. See also [How do I convert from int to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string) if want to to know how to convert your `int` to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

`Log.i(Size);` method expecting `Log.i(String,String)` and you are giving `Log.i(int)` that's why it is not compiling.

Comment: You have to pass `String` values,e.g. `Log.i("array length : ",String.valueOf(size))`

Comment: @Kala can you post i() method, if you are implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Log an **int**. You need to pass it two strings (a tag and message). Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html