# Convert int to String

Tags: java

```
private JTextField resultTextField;
resultTextField.setText(" "); ...

private class InputListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Stack<Integer> operandStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();

        String input = inputTextField.getText();

        StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input, " ", false);


        while (strToken.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String i = strToken.nextToken();
            int operand;
            char operator;

            try
            {
                operand = Integer.parseInt(i);
                operandStack.push(operand);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                operator = i.charAt(0);
                operatorStack.push(operator);
            }
        }
        int result = sum (operandStack, operatorStack);
        resultTextField.setText(result);
```

The last line that reads: "resultTextField.setText(result);" in the code provided, I'm trying to convert the 'result' variable to a String but having no success. The compile error message I get is:

```
PrefixExpression.java:96: error: method setText in class JTextComponent cannot be applied to given types;
          resultTextField.setText(result);
                         ^
  required: String
  found: int
  reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion.
```

I've tried several methods already provided in answers to other 'convert int to String' questions in here, but none of them work. How do I convert 'result' to a String? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us the methods that you tried and what the problem with them was.

Comment: what is the problem with `Integer.toString(result)`

Comment: @singhakash `result` is `int`, not `Integer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will convert an int to a string:

```
resultTextField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned below there is no need to import java.lang as it will be available always.

Comment: You never need to import the `java.lang.*` library.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to remove the import.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Integer.toString(number) or String.valueOf(number) function. This function can take  an integer and turn it into a String.
Try adding:

```
String numResult = Integer.toString(result);
```

or

```
String numResult = String.valueOf(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a hack

```
resultTextField.setText(result + "");
```

Comment: Moishe, thank you, it worked! YAHOOOOOOO!

Comment: Actually, @Jeremy, this is considered bad practice.

Comment: @RealSkeptic RealSkeptic, what is  considered bad practice, the code that Moishe Lipsker provided or my comment to him or her?

Comment: @MoisheLipsker I just noticed the words, "You could do a hack." How Cool! My first time hacking! Okay :-( not cool.

Comment: @Jeremy I meant the code. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105406/4125191) which explains this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I read 'this answer' that you provided, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @RealSkeptic All of the answers I received worked, so why can't I give a green check mark to them all?

Comment: Only one answer can be marked as the correct answer you were looking for. However, all answers can be upvoted (multiple times) if they are on track and provide something useful.

Comment: @MoisheLipsker Thanks, Moishe, I upvoted them all! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this: `(new Integer(result)).toString()` and you should be OK.

Comment: Wouldn't `Integer.toString(result)` be neater?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, sure.

Comment: Besides neater, it will create one less object.