# JButton set the button text to a variable

Tags: java

I will make a java game similar to cookie clickers, but is seems that I can't put a variable as a text in the button.

**This is what is causing the problems, because the variable isn't a string(I cut out the other part of the code, because it's not important for now):**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Frame {

    public static int num1 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Cookie Clicker");
        JButton b1 = new JButton(num1);

        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(b1);
    }
}
```

As you can see there's the num1 variable in there and it won't let it to be there. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: You have to convert the `int` number to a `String`, e.g. `new JButton(String.valueOf(num1))`

Comment: The `JButton` function is `public JButton(String text, Icon icon)`. Where `icon` is provided by default if not passed. But the text should be `String`. You can do `new JButton(""+num1);`

Comment: ok, both ways work, but how do I change the text in the GridLayout buttons by a code?

This is the code for one GridLayout button:

buttonPanel1.add(new JButton(num1 + " Cookies!"));

Comment: oh nevermind.. I din't realize something.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the value of int to String:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton(String.valueOf(num1));
```

Answer (score 3):

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html

[image]

There exists **no** constructor for the following:

```
new JButton(int);
```

For converting **int to String** see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ... more specifically, use:

[image]

Example use of String.valueOf(int):

```
int fiveInt = 5;
String fiveString = String.valueOf(fiveInt); // sets fiveString value="5"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a string representation of your integer variable, as described here: [How do I convert from int to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4105331/535275).

Comment: Although the information presented in your link is useful, just linking to a source isn't usually considered a quality answer. Can you elaborate?