# Searching a String for an integer. Datatype mismatch?

Tags: java, string, casting, char, int

I'm trying to compare a 4 digit String using charAt(x) to an integer in order to find out how many of that integer there is in the string.

```
public static boolean tickets(int numbers) {

int a = (numbers/100000);
int b = (numbers/10000) - a*10;
int c = numbers - a*100000 - b*10000;
int x = 0;
int count = 0;
String s = String.valueOf(c);

if (numbers/100000 == 0 || numbers/100000 > 9 ) { 
  return false;                                  
}
if (numbers <= 0) {
  return false;
} 

while (x < 4) {
  if (s.charAt(x) == a ) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  x = x + 1;
      }

if (count == b) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}}
```

I'm not going to insult anyone's intelligence and say this isn't a homework problem: it is. The prompt is to input a number (if negative, or not 6 digits, return '`false`'). To get a return of '`true`' the number has to have the first digit the second digit's number of times in the last for digits (what?!). For example, 121001 would return `true` since 1 occers 2 times in the last 4 digits.

Anyway, my problem is that even though `s.charAt(x)` will have the same value as `a`, at least when I print them out and check (i.e. they'll both print 9's or something), my `count`variable doesn't seem to budge. Do I have a datatype mismatch? What can I do to fix this? Or have I approached this problem the wrong way entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to read a little bit about the difference of primitive types. `charAt()` obviously returns a char value ... which yes, can be compared to an int number, but what exactly makes you think that the character "1" for example is "equal" to 1? [ hint: it is not ... you want to checkout on stuff like ASCII, codepages, and all the like ]

Comment: side note `(if negative, or not 6 digits, return 'false')` just need `if (numbers<100000){return false;}` no need of that calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the data type mismatch. Character '0' does not equal to integer 0. One quick fix could be:

```
if (s.charAt(x) == a + '0' ) {
    count = count + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is always false, because the data types do not match...

Try and use this as your if statements condition:

```
 if(Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(x)+"") == a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading through this: [Convert from Integer to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string).

Basically, you could create a new String variable called `aString` and set it to `Integer.toString(a)`.