# JMeter BeanShell - integer to string

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Just trying to convert an integer to a string.

```
vars.put("test", i);
```

I'd like to put the value in the variable "test", but it does not working and I think I must convert the int to a string. 
But I have no idea how to do that.
I just found a out how to parsing string to integer in BeanShellSampler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [String.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) method

```
vars.put("test", String.valueOf(i));
```

Additional information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter - [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Answer (score 3):

There is yet a shortcut way, how to cast an `int i` to `String s`:

> `String s = ""+i;` .. just that simple!

So the asked example:

> `vars.put("test", ""+i);`

..Seriously, nobody gave that answer yet? See i.e. [4105331](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-string) for further info.

Answer (score -1):

BeanShell is a Java scripting language, so anything that works in Java should work in BeanShell, too.

I tend to use
`vars.put("test", new Integer(i).toString());`

If `i` is already an `Integer`, you only need to do `vars.put("test", i.toString());`