# Convert specific int array to String

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I have variable int array like this

```
int[] sample = new int[];
sample[0] = 1;
sample[1] = 2;

String two = sample[1].toString(); <==== i have problem with this

System.out.println(two);
```

how to resolve them?
i cannot to show value of int[1] as string..

Comment: you mean `sample[1]` instead of `int[1]`, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do

```
int i = 2;
String two = i.toString();  // or sample[1].toString();
```

As `int` is a [primitive type](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139747/what-is-meant-by-a-primitive-data-type), not an object. As you're working with the `int[] sample` array, notice that while `sample` is an object, `sample[1]` is just an `int`, so the primitive type again.

Instead, you should do

```
int i = 2;
String two = String.valueOf(i); // or String.valueOf(sample[1]);
```

But if your problem is just printing the value to `System.out`, it has a [`println(int x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)) method, so you can simply do

```
int i = 2;
System.out.println(i);  // or System.out.println(sample[1]);
```

Now, if you want to print the complete representation of your array, do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sample));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
String two = sample[1].toString(); <==== i have problem with this
```

To this:

```
String two = String.valueOf(sample[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way to what @ericbn has proposed. You can create `Integer` object from your int primitive type and then use `toString` method to get the String value of it:

```
Integer I = new Integer(i);
System.out.println(I.toString());
```

Comment: Not the best practice though, as it creates an intermediate wrapper object.

Comment: And you should always use `Integer.valueOf` instead.

Comment: @chrylis where do you mean?

Comment: Don't use `new Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it with String.valueOf() of instead toString().
The program can be edited as,

```
int[] sample = new int[];
int[0] = 1;
int[1] = 2;

String two = String.valueOf(int[1]);
System.out.println(two);
```

I hope this will help you.

You can also refer following link [int to string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string)

Answer (score -1):

Another solution can be-

```
String two = sample[1]+"";//concatenate with empty String
System.out.println(two);
```

Comment: Another bad practice!