# C# How to make a return function?

Tags: c#, function

So i have a question. I'm trying do make a `function witch returns a number`, but the problem is that i can't convert `int` to `string`. My functions looks like this:

```
    static string EnemyDmg(EnemyDmg _dmg)
    {
        string result = "";
         int EnemyDmg
             = CharAttack - EnemyDefense;
        if (EnemyDmg < 1)
            EnemyDmg = 4;
        result = EnemyDmg;
        return result;
    }
```

but it should do this

```
     int EnemyDmg
          = CharAttack - EnemyDefense;
     if (EnemyDmg < 1)
     EnemyDmg = 4;
     Console.WriteLine(EnemyName + "  takes  " + EnemyDmg + "  Damage");
```

has anyone an idea?

PS: The 4 is just a random number.

Comment: Eh, `result=EnemyDmg.ToString();` ?

Comment: These are extremely poorly-named variables and functions.

Comment: If you want the function to return a number then why are you returning a string? A string is text, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

should be `static int EnemyDmg(EnemyDmg _dmg)`. You should return an int, and convert to string outside the function iif you need that

Anyway, to convert a String s into an int i:

```
int i = Int32.Parse(s);
```

to convert an int i into a string s

```
string s = i.ToString();
string s = ""+i; // more "java-like"
```

Comment: `""+i` is more java like? Apart from the fact that it's irrelevant it is `Integer.toString(i)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit ambiguous; I'm not sure why you've done it this way.

You can convert a C# integer to a string with the .ToString() method, like this:

```
int a = 12;
string aString = a.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/sMC3hU

Answer (score 0):

```
    static string toStr(int intInput)
    {
        string str = intInput.ToString();
        return str;
    }

    }
```

This code will do it for you. There is no need to use if statement as there is no any specific requirement, it will make more complicated code.

or else

you can direct use ToString parameter if there is an user input just refer to the 3rd line.