# Why does .setText() cause a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

Why does this code throws `ClassCastException`.when I am trying to set selected row value of JTable(`ie.showItem`) to a TextField (`ie.itemCode`).Exception is `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

```
 showItem = new JTable();
        showItem.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int rowCount=showItem.getRowCount();
                if(rowCount>=1){
                    //Why it is throwing ClassCastException
                     itemCode.setText((String)showItem.getValueAt(showItem.getSelectedRow(), 0));

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Because the object that is returned from `getValueAt` - an Integer, as indicated by the exception message - cannot be cast as a String. This has nothing to do with `setText` and is caused by the expression used as the argument. Was there another question?

Comment: @Mukund show itemCode class

Comment: use .toString() method

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't try to write all your code in a single statement. Its is easier to debug using multiple statements:

```
itemCode.setText((String)showItem.getValueAt(showItem.getSelectedRow(), 0));
```

Can easily be written as:

```
Object value = showItem.getValueAt(rowCount, 0);
itemCode.setText( value.toString() );
```

Note there is no need to invoke the getSelectedRow() method twice since you have a variable that contains that value.

Then you can always add some debug code like:

```
Object value = showItem.getValueAt(rowCount, 0);
System.out.println( value.getClass() );
```

to see what type of Object your table has in that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check this.

[How do I convert from int to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-string)

for

```
itemCode.setText((String)showItem.getValueAt(showItem.getSelectedRow(), 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an `Integer` to `String`, because `Integer` *is not* a `String`, that is, `Integer` is not a subclass of `String`. However, you can pass the `Integer` to a `String`, since all `Object` have the `toString()` method.

```java
Integer a = new Integer( 10 );
String myString = "" + a;
//Is the same  as String myString = "" + a.toString(), so you could do just
//String myString = a.toString();
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)