# How do I display a Random number generated in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, random

I am generating random flashes of a button and I want to know what exact number is being chosen each time so I can eventually add them to an `ArrayList` for a project I am undergoing.

```
TextView randomTextView;
Random r = new Random();

private void sequenceFunction() {
    //Change Alpha from Fully Visible to Invisible
    final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    //Duration - A Second
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    //Animation Rate
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setStartOffset(250);
    animation.setDuration(250);
    //Repeat Animation
    animation.setRepeatCount(r.nextInt(10));

    // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    //Button 1 Flashes
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.startAnimation(animation);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            view.clearAnimation();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to display the result of what ever random number has been generated via the randomTextView `TextView`. This part is critical so that I know that the random function is working as it is supposed to. I have already tried

```
randomTextView.setText(r.nextInt(10));
```

However it didn't like it. Any ideas on how to get the random number selected would be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: `randomTextView.setText("" + r.nextInt(10));`

Comment: what don't you like about `randomTextView.setText(r.nextInt(10))` ?

Comment: @TWL `setText()` needs a CharSequence or a resource id. Which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps -

```
private void sequenceFunction() {
    //Change Alpha from Fully Visible to Invisible
    final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    //Duration - A Second
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    //Animation Rate
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setStartOffset(250);
    //Repeat Animation
    int randomValue = r.nextInt();
    // code to add value to array
    animation.setRepeatCount(randomValue);
    randomTextView.setText(String.valueOf(randomValue));

    // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    //Button 1 Flashes
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.startAnimation(animation);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            view.clearAnimation();
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have look in the documentation of `TextView`, you can see that `setText(int)` actually expects a resource id: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

So you have to turn your int to a CharSequence, you could simply do

```
randomTextView.setText("" + r.nextInt(10));
```

which converts your integer to a string.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply how would I get the number of animation.setRepeatCount(r.nextInt(10)); as when I do the randomTextView.setText(r.nextInt(10)+""); it sees it as a new random number and not the one I am using to generate the animation flashes ?

Comment: In this case, just store the value in a variable like this:


`int randomNumber = r.nextInt(10);`
 `animation.setRepeatCount(randomNumber);`
 `...`
 `randomTextView.setText(Integer.toString(random));`

Comment: save `r.nextint(10)` in some variable then pass it to `animation.setRepeatCount()` and use it anywhere.

Comment: @SimMac Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105406/2948765) for an explanation why `"" + ...` is bad style.

Answer (score 0):

[`TextView.setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) can be used with either a [resource ID](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) (which is an integer) or with a [`CharSequence`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html), for example a [`String`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html).

There are many ways to do this, including

```
int random = r.nextInt(10);
randomTextView.setText(String.valueOf(random);
randomTextView.setText(Integer.toString(random);
randomTextView.setText(String.format("%d", random);
```

Do *not* use `"" + r.nextInt(10)`. I know, it is short, it is handy, but it is simply inefficient and bad style.

Comment: Hi thanks for the recorrection however how would I use this to get the exact random number that is being generated by animation.setRepeatCount(r.nextInt(10)); ?

Comment: This code displays the generated number in the `TextView`. If you want to use the number multiple times, you will need to cache it in a variable like this: `int number = r.nextInt(10); randomTextView.setText(String.valueOf(number));` and then use the variable `number`.