# How can I find the length of a String from another method?

Tags: java, methods

```
package hollyhw;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class HollyHW {
    public static int censor(String chars){
```

> I tried implementing the following. However, I did not manage.

```
        int letters = chars.length();
        int newLetters = letters;

        return newLetters;   
    }
```

> Note that for this specific task, I cannot edit the void main.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String c1 = censor("short"); //IDE is suggesting to change to int.
        String c2 = censor("longer the short"); //IDE is suggesting to change to int.
        String c3 = censor("the longest one we've got"); //IDE is suggesting to change to int.

        print(c1);
        print(c2);
        print(c3);
        print("");
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to *convert* the `int` to a `String`?! Shortest way `return "" + newLetters;` + change the return type of the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert from int to String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public static String lengthAsString(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    return Integer.toString(len);   
}
```