# How do I store a int in a String?

Tags: java

How can I store a `int` value in a `String`?

For example:

```
int number = 10;
string word = number;
```

Comment: Does above code has shown an error if yes then what is it.

Comment: s of string should be capital

Comment: `String word = String.valueOf(number)` ... literally 10 seconds of Googling would have revealed this.  This isn't the best way to use this site.

Comment: use String word=number+""

Comment: @javafan String word=number+"" is bad parctice to convert int to String

Comment: @AmitBera Ok i will try to use valueOf instead

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the static method:

```
String.valueOf(number)
```

Or

```
new Integer(number).toString();
```

Comment: Do not use the last way, as it creates a new Integer instance. Thats is not performant.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 10;
string word = Integer.toString(number);
```

this will convert the integer "number" to string to be able to store it inside a string without changing it's value
just that easy, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to convert an int to string.

```
String word = Integer.toString(number);

String word = String.valueOf(number);

String word = new Integer(number).toString();

String word = String.format ("%d", number);

etc..
```

There are more ways to do this. But I prefer the 1st one. 
Just do some googling you will find more answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Normal ways would be `Integer.toString(number)` or `String.valueOf(number)`.
But, You can try this:

```
int number = 10;
String str = String.valueOf(number);
```

**Or**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("");
sb.append(number);
String str = sb.toString();
```