# ANDROID STUDIO: I need help in converting a code in java that returns an int from MYSQL database into a string (SHAREDPREFERENCES)

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, sharedpreferences

So, I have a database that returns 2 integer-type values (`1 = USD`  and `3 = GHS`). I wrote an API PHP code that returns the integer values and would like to convert their corresponding String (`USD` and `GHS`) in Java.

The line of code that returns the int in java (android studio) is

```
creditnav.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getUser().getCurrency());
```

I would like to return the result of the above line of code into their corresponding strings.

How do I go about it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert from int to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-string)

Comment: Please do provide enough detail so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
int currencyCode = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getUser().getCurrency();
if (currencyCode == 1) {
    creditnav.setText("USD");
}
if (currencyCode == 3) {
    creditnav.setText("GHS");
}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much. This solved my issue.

`code`
int currencyCode = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser().getCurrency();
        if (currencyCode == 1) {
            credit.setText("$"+ " " + SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser().getCredit());

            currency.setText("USD");
        }
        if (currencyCode == 3) {
            credit.setText("GHS"+ " " + SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser().getCredit());

            currency.setText("GHS");
        }

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the getCurrency() and add a switch/if else statement and return a string, or create another method getCurrencyString()

```
switch (currencyInteger) {
  case 1 :
      return "USD";

  case 2 :
      return "GHS";

  default:
      // Handle this
      break;
}
```

Comment: how would a switch statement like this be implemented using the sharedpreference code i shared. Can you write the full code using the sharedpreference code?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one if it may help you :).

```
 String creds=SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getUser().getCurrency(); 


if (creds.getText().toString.equals("1")) {
  creditnav.setText("USD");
}
else if (creds.getText().toString.equals("3")) {
   creditnav.setText("GHS");
```

}

Comment: I think the String at the beginning of the creds must be an int. Thanks for the answer