# IndexOf()Method to find a number problem in a string

Tags: java

package com.company;

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s="1239586838923173478943890234092";
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                int count=0;
                int k=-1;
                while(s.indexOf(i+"",k+1)!=-1){
                    k=s.indexOf(i+"",k+1);
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println(i+"出现的次数是"+count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here,

```
indexOf(i+"",k+1)
```

`i+""` ?  why?  what's means?

Comment: Did you take a look how indexOf works?

Comment: See the doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int)) accepts the argument of type `String` and `int`.

The code in your block as

```
i + ""
```

is used to convert the number of type `int` into a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

`i + ""` is one way of converting an `int` into a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a (very ugly) way to convert an int into a String.

See [How do I convert from int to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-string)  for better ways.