# Android: How to set text of radio button into an Integer?

Tags: java, android

I am needing to retrieve the values from a RadioGroup and set the Text on the Radio Buttons to an Integer based on the loan term.

**PurchaseActivity.java**

```
 Auto mAuto;

// THE DATA TO BE PASSED TO THE LOAN ACTIVITY
String loanReport;
String monthlyPayment;

// LAYOUT INPUT REFERENCES
EditText carPriceET;
EditText downPayET;
RadioGroup loanTermRG;

private void collectAutoInputData() {
    // TASK 1: SET THE CAR PRICE
    mAuto.setPrice ((double) Integer.valueOf(carPriceET.getText()
            .toString()));

    //TASK 2: SET THE DOWN PAYMENT
    mAuto.setDownPayment((double)
            Integer.valueOf(downPayET.getText()
                    .toString()));

    //TASK 3 SET THE LOAN TERM
    Integer radioId = loanTermRG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton term = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioId);
    mAuto.setLoanTerm(term.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert from int to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.valueOf();

```
  mAuto.setLoanTerm(String.valueOf(term.getText()));
```