# how to allow predefined amount of entries to java program

Tags: java, command-line

My program allows the user to enter 20 entries. each entry is entered as one entry then presses enter from command line. I would like to add the ability for the program to say 
"you have 20 entries left"
then 
"you have 19 entries left"
and so on... as the user enters more data in to the program.

I would appreciate if someone could show me the simplest way to add this to my current code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class project02Diaz
{   
    private static Double calculate_average( ArrayList<Double> myArr )
    {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        for (Double number: myArr)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum/myArr.size(); 
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner           scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> myArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int               count = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter one number at a time be averaged, you have 20 entries remaining:");

        for (String inputs = scan.nextLine() ; !inputs.matches("[qQ]")  ; inputs = scan.nextLine())
        {
            if (count == 20)
            {
                System.out.println("You entered more than 20 numbers, you suck!");
                break;
            }
            try{
                myArr.add(Double.valueOf(inputs));
                count++; 
                System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Try again you tard! You entered more than one number, or not a valid number at all.");
                continue;                   
            }      

        }
        Double average = calculate_average(myArr);
        System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have made minimum changes to your code to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You again! Allright, going to do that one, too. There isn't too much that you have to change: simply count your counter down from twenty and output it's stauts every time. Also, stop if you reach 0.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner           scan        = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Double> myArr       = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int               entriesLeft = 20; // changed counter that counts upwards to one counting down.

    System.out.println("Enter one number at a time be averaged, you have 20 entries remaining:");

    // added additional condition to be checked: we now also stop if maximum number of entries ie reached.
    for (String inputs = scan.nextLine() ; entriesLeft > 0 && !inputs.matches("[qQ]")  ; inputs = scan.nextLine())
    {
        try{
            myArr.add(Double.valueOf(inputs));
            entriesLeft--; //counting one down
            System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");
            // telling user how much numbers are left
            System.out.println("You have " + entriesLeft + "numbers left.");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Try again you tard! You entered more than one number, or not a valid number at all.");
            continue;                   
        }      

    }
    Double average = calculate_average(myArr);
    System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
}
```

Note that appending the integer `entriesLeft` to the string isn't super efficient, the nicer way is to call `Integer.toString(entriesLeft)`.

Comment: The `toString()`? FOr performance reasons. Strings are **immutalbe** (that is: they cannot be modified once created). `""+number` creates three strings: "", "15" (assuming `number` is 15), and "15" again (as the result).

Comment: See, for example, here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802684/integer-to-string-conversion-methods

Comment: ok gonna read up on it thanks. Now the last thing I am gonna do is change Integer.toString or figure out how thanks!

Comment: would you show me what you mean with the Integer.ToString?

Comment: This: `System.out.println("You have " + Integer.toString(entriesLeft) + " numbers left");`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
class project02Diaz
{   
    private static Double calculate_average( ArrayList<Double> myArr )
{
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for (Double number: myArr)
    {
        sum += number;
    }
    return sum/myArr.size(); 
}

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner           scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> myArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int               count = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter one number at a time be averaged, you have 20 entries remaining:");

        for (String inputs = scan.nextLine() ; !inputs.matches("[qQ]")  ; inputs = scan.nextLine())
        {
        System.out.println("You have "+ String.valueOf(20 - count -1) +" number of enteries left");
        if (count == 19)
            {
                System.out.println("You entered more than 20 numbers, you suck!");
                break;
            }
            try{
                myArr.add(Double.valueOf(inputs));
                count++; 
                System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Try again you tard! You entered more than one number, or not a valid number at all.");
                continue;                   
            }      
        }
        Double average = calculate_average(myArr);
        System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution outputs the current stauts even if something invalid was entered - and it does so AFTER input was read, not before new oin is accepted. You migth want to move the output down, to where an actual number is added.